# How to copy an unknown type of data in Fortran?

Tags: list, fortran, copy

Assume now I have a type `data` in a module (called module A)

```
type::data
endtype
```

The definition left empty. In future I will extend it to any type,for instant:

```
type,extends(data)::newdata
   ...(something general data )
endtype
```

Now what I want is to define a process in module A to copy `newdata` type. Is it possible? Something as following:

```
subroutine copyBtoA(A,B)
 class(data),pinter::A
 class(data)::B
 A <- B
endsubroutine
```

Even though we do not know what the type `newdata` looks like, here `A` is a pointer and I guess we can allocate it according to `B` somehow?

---

To be more clear, what I want to do is define a list structure. Since it is a structure, the type `data` is not defined yet (in module A). However I want to define a function to copy data type. The point is that I want to copy a data which is NOT defined yet. Logically it looks little strange.

When the subroutine `copyBtoA` is called, the input A and B, in fact, is of type `newdata`. And here in moduleA A is not allocated yet. If in the definition I use `Allocate(A)`, I think it is of type `data`. Then `A=B` is impossible. If I use `select type`, then I do not know the type yet.

```
!---------------------------example code---------------

module moduleA
   type::data
   endtype
 contains
   subroutine copyBtoA(A,B)
     type(data),allocatable::A
     type(data)::B
     !-------------------
     A = B
   endsubroutine
endmodule

module moduleB
  use moduleA
  type,extends(data)::newdata
     real::something
  endtype
endmodule

program main
use moduleB
!
type(newdata),allocatable::data2
type(newdata)::data1
data1%something = 1.
! call copyBtoA(data2,data1)
endprogram
```

Comment: Your syntax  is not correct Fortran.

Comment: What is wrong with `A=B` or `A=>B` as appropriate?

Comment: Perhaps he is getting an error, that a polymorphic assignment is not allowed (ise. implemented) in gfortran. But the question should be made clearer. @hengyueli Please show us the code where you need to do this copy.

Comment: Here I just posted a question and I wonder if it is possible. I do not have the code yet. If I do what @francescalus suggested, A = B. What is the meaning since A is a pointer? If I use A=>B, B will be pointed but not copied.

Comment: As Vladimir F's comment suggested, I wonder why you have problems with `A=B`.  With `A` allocatable such polymorphic assignment is possible _with compiler support_.  It isn't clear to me whether you have Fortran problems or design problems.

Comment: You mean we can use A=B even A is an unallocated pointer?@francescalus

Comment: Not pointer, but allocatable. The allocation is then automatic. You can always use sourced allocation too (even for pointers) `allocate(A, source=B)`. But that **copies** everything, think whether you don't need **pointer assignment** instead. I still don't understand your intention. Code is better than a lot of words.

Comment: I realy do not know how to show a code since I do not know how to realize it. Here I show a code showed what I want to do. Of cause calling of "copyBtoA" will give a error. @Vladimir F @ francescalus

Comment: As shown in the code, I only want to define the subroutine copyBtoA in moduleA since moduleB will be changed according to a different project.

Comment: Th point is we wont to know how you want to use it. Then, after knowing the real purpose, we can help you create it. It is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With non-polymorphic variables there is really no problem, at least with the program you show.

Maybe your code does not really show the real intended usage after all? You first spoke about some list structure and in the end you only show some simple program...

You can just use the default assignment

```
type(newdata),allocatable::data2
type(newdata)::data1
data1%something = 1.

data2 = data1
```

In Fortran 2008 you you can do that even with **polymorphics**, that means you **do NOT directly see** `type(newdata)`

```
class(data),allocatable::data1,data2
class(data)::data1
allocate(newdata::data1)

data2 = data1
```

is enough.

In gfortran this is not yet supported. You have to do

```
class(data),allocatable::data1,data2
class(data)::data1
allocate(newdata::data1)

allocate(data2, source = data1)
```

There is always a possibility to override the assignment by a user defined subroutine, but it is not really necessary here. You would likely have to define the assignment also for type newdata.

---

But remember, all this is **copying the value**. In your very first code snippet you had a pointer. With pointers you often do pointer assignment `=>` and that is something else.

Comment: It still looks different from what I want. As you showed, all the assignment are all at where type(newdata) can be "saw". I want to call the subroutine CopyBtoA at outside of moduleA, but define CopyBtoA in moduleA.  My original requirement is to built a list structure. It contains some operations. But the exact definition will be an extended type outside.     Therefore, I expected in the definition of CopyBtoA contains class(data), not type(data).

Comment: By the way, the reason I use pointer is that I want to save all the newdata. I can only come up with this way. I create all the data of type(newdata) by pointers, then I can pass these pointers into moduleA.

Comment: a grammar mistake in my comments: saw -> seen. Please do not be confused with it.

Comment: It was YOU who wrote the example code with `type(newdata)`! If you want different usage, you must show us the code you want to write, I can't read your mind. The code I show **DOES** work for polymorphics, that means it **DOES** work for `class(data)`. Just try it. It is all in the answer. I say again, **read the answer**, it is **`class(data)`**, not `type(newdata)`.

Comment: If you want to do a list structure, show us the **real example code**, not your `program main` which is useless. Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem There is no problem with copying A to B and it is all in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the reply. Even though I think the real solution is still no gotten, however, I think this is absolutely an XY problem which traps me a lot. Then I guess I need to ask about the original problem. Should I close this topic or just left it?

Comment: Please read the answer again. The question about copying is answered there. Just try it. **You do NOT need any such subroutine.** I don't think you should delete this question (after I put quite a lot of work to answer it), you should rather polish it somehow. You can ask a new question with the refined problem for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160246/discussion-between-hengyue-li-and-vladimir-f).